# Mercurial does not send emails using changenotify

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

I set up a http central Mercurial repository and try to send emails on every push. I follow instructions from mercurial page and from http://morecode.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/setting-up-mercurial-to-e-mail-on-a-commit/.

Push works fine, but I don't see any notify message at all. Please help me.

My .hg/hgrc in my repository folder of my client looks like this

```
[extensions]
hgext.notify= 

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = what@gmail.com

[smtp]
host = smtp.gmail.com
username = what@gmail.com
password = ohyea
port = 587
tls = true

[web]
baseurl = http://1.1.1.1/repo_name

[notify]
sources = serve push pull bundle

# set this to False when you're ready for mail to start sending
test = False

config = /home/myhome/something/subscription.conf

template = \ndetails:   {baseurl}{webroot}/rev/{node|short}\nchangeset:{rev}:node|short}\nuser:      {author}\ndate:      {date|date}\ndescription:\n{desc}\n

maxdiff = 300
```

My /home/myhome/something/subscription.conf looks like

```
[reposubs]
# key is glob pattern, value is comma-separated list of subscriber emails
* = sometestemail@gmail.com
```

I save and my result looks like below, if you notice I don't see any notify message at all

```
pushing to http://1.1.1.1/repo_name
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 2 changesets with 7376 changes to 7376 files
```

[Update:]

I found that there was no hgext folder in my system. So I manually downloaded the source matching my hg version and updated my hgrc as below, and still it does not work. Any help please.

```
[extensions]
notify= /path/to/notify.py
```

[Update 2:]

Thanks Ry4an - I tried it, still no luck.

In my webserver

Under /var/www and /var/www/hg
I created .hgrc files, just not sure which one is my webroot, so I did at both places with contents

```
[trusted]
users=user_name
```

this user name is the username in my client from where I'm trying to push to the repo.

on my client

in the .hg/hgrc of my repo, I added trusted section

```
[trusted]
users=user_name
```

The above procedure did not help

Second approach

on my client,

under my repo's .hg, I did

```
chown www-data:www-data hgrc
```

and when I tried to push I got some message while pushing saying

```
sending capabilities command
capabilities: changegroupsubset stream lookup pushkey unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN branchmap
sending heads command
searching for changes
common changesets up to 6ef19c49143a
sending branchmap command
ignoring untrusted configuration option hooks.changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
```

This ignoring command does not appear during the first approach, only after I change the ownership of hgrc, this pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely a trust issue, but let's hit a few other things first:

A) Switch the extension load  to:

```
[extensions]
notify=
```

The hgext part is no longer necessary, but doesn't hurt.  Giving the full path to the extension is more fragile in the case of future updates.  The raw `notify=` syntax is sufficient for extensions that come with Mercurial and notify always does.

B) Switch the `test = false` to `test = true` it will help you debug this -- it sends the email to Stdout, which is handy.

Okay, those two done, let's look at trust.  Mercurial's trust system is built around the idea that not just anyone should be able to get you to run code.  Imagine if your repo's `.hg/hgrc` file had a section in it like:

```
[hooks]
pre-push = rm -rf ~
```

When I pushed to it it would delete my home directory.  That would bum me out.  To avoid  that happening Mercurial will only load/run hgrc files that it trusts, and you tell it what to trust with `[trusted]` sections in *your* hgrc.  When you're pushing over ssh you're effectively logging into the remote machine and it's your own `~/.hgrc` that probably states what other hgrc files you're willing to execute.

HTTP is special though.  Even though you may be authenticating you're probably not running Mercurial on the remote system as yourself.  It's probably some some non-user user like *www-data*, *www*, *apache*, or *noone* depending on how your web server is configured, so... you need to make that repo's `.hg/hgrc' owned (or group-owned) by an user (or group) that the webserver user trusts.  To achieve that you can either`chwown`the`.hg/hgrc`file over to the web server user, or find the web server's home directory (often`/var/www`) and create a`.hgrc`file in there with a`[trusted]`block saying that the web server user trusts whomever it is that owns the repo's`.hg/hgrc` file.

If I'm right about what's going on the tell tale sign would be in your webserver's errors log where you'd see a lot of messages like "Not trusting /path/to/repo/.hg/hgrc owned by someuser".

**TL;DR:** Make sure your web server user trusts (in the hgrc sense) the owner of the `.hg/hgrc` that's specifying the hook.

Comment: Thanks - i tried it - still no luck , please see the update 2 section in my post. Thanks again for help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when communicating with an Exchange Server:

```
[hostfingerprints]
<my exchange FQDN> = 2a:f3:89:69:13:b2:1e:3a:c2:fe:f9:7f:de:b3:39:e7:82:8e:99:93

[extensions]
notify =

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = Mercurial Notification <noreply@mydomain>

[smtp]
host = <exchange FQDN>
tls = true

[notify]
sources = serve push pull bundle
test = False
maxdiff = 300

[reposubs]
* = Cameron Rich <cameron.rich@mydomain.com>
```

Put the above in the hgrc file in your repository.

e.g. C:\repositories\test.hg\hgrc